# How to keep the subWindow on the top of the Application

Tags: cocoa

I have a sub window (`similar to Inspector window in keyNote`) on the top of the application.How can I make the subwindow always on the front of my application ? In other words the subwindow should not be allowed to place on any other application.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling `Hide On Deactivate` for the NSWindow in the Interface Builder I was able to keep the subWind.